React native splash screen will not disappear
I am new to React Native and I am trying to implement a splash screen by using the following guide:
https://medium.com/@svbala99/set-up-splash-screen-in-react-native-for-ios-and-android-2023-dbedb87fe75e
I have only implemented the Android part since I am working on a Windows computer.
The splash screen does show when I run "npm run android" but it never disappears again so I think that the useEffect in the guide does not work:
useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }, []);

This is my entire App.tsx code:
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import type {PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

type SectionProps = PropsWithChildren<{
  title: string;
}>;

function Section({children, title}: SectionProps): React.JSX.Element {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionTitle,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          },
        ]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionDescription,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.light : Colors.dark,
          },
        ]}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

// Should hide the Splash screen
  useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
        backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
      />
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={backgroundStyle}>
        <Header />
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          }}>
          <Section title="Step One">
            Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.tsx</Text> to change this
            screen and then come back to see your edits.
          </Section>
          <Section title="See Your Changes">
            <ReloadInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Debug">
            <DebugInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Learn More">
            Read the docs to discover what to do next:
          </Section>
          <LearnMoreLinks />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

export default App;

I have tried to research the problem and found the following:
Splash screen does not hide
However, the solution to this problem does not solve my problem. The splash screen does not disappear or fade away once the app have been loaded.
Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

react-native-splash-screen last updated is 3 years ago so the package might not supported recent version of react native, here's another alternative react-native-bootsplash
